# Automatically open a pull request on github by command line

Tags: git, github, automation, fork, push

I'm using git to versioning a collaborate project.

And I have two remotes. **fork** is a fork of an **project**, and **origin** is the original project.

So, could I when I send a push (git push fork master) automatically create a pull request available in **origin** to merge it?

I can't commit directly to **origin** (I know this is possible). I need push first to **fork** and if the admin aproves it, accept on **origin**. I would like automate this process, avoiding me to manually go to github and open a fork.

How could I do this?

**Edit:**

Private Organization:

```
name: Org
repository: main
branch: master
```

Private Fork:

```
name: OrgFork (A organization of mine with forks from **Org**) 
repository: main
branch: testing
```

I tried the following approach, but didn't worked yet:

```
curl -X POST -u <Username> -k -d '{"title": "<Title>","head": "Org:main","base": "testing"}' https://api.github.com/repos/Org/main/pulls
```

what is wrong? How can I fix this?

**Edit 2**

Another attempt:

```
hub pull-request "Testing" -b OrgFork:main:testing -h OrgFork:main:master
```

Comment: Github has [an API for creating pull requests](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) that may be of some use.

Comment: @cjc343 , I had take a look on this, but I couldnt put to work.

Comment: A big part of using the API is authenticating. You'll need an [application](https://github.com/settings/applications) and to generate OAuth tokens via an [authorization](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization). There's a nice introduction [using curl](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960).

Comment: @cjc343, this tutorial didnt worked for me. I tried several things. One like:  curl https://api.github.com/authorizations --user "GarouDan" --data '{"scopes":["hub"],"note":"Hub"}' to get a new auth but I received "Bad credentials". (tried "garoudan" too). The [hub](http://defunkt.io/hub/) project writes the OAuth run in the first time, but at my config in GitHub I dont have nothing about this.

Comment: I had solve the problem with the credentials. Now I'm trying to create the pull-request, please see **Edit 2**. No success yet.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is no error description. What exactly didn't work? What error messages did you receive? http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please answer these at least in your next questions.

Comment: Why are you using -k for curl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally success

The first problem is that I was using the key password and not my github password.

With this structure:

Private Organization:

```
name: Org
repository: main
branch: master
```

Private Fork:

```
name: OrgFork (A organization of mine with forks from **Org**) 
repository: main
branch: testing
```

And the other problem is I was needing accept the corrects parameters, the final command looks like this one:

```
hub pull-request "Testing pull-request" -b Org:master -h OrgFork:testing
```

Thx for help @cjc343, @StevenPenny, @desert69 =)

Answer (score 10):

You should check out [`hub`](http://defunkt.io/hub/), a command line tool to interact with GitHub.

[Its README](https://github.com/defunkt/hub#git-pull-request) talks about making pull requests.

Comment: Unfortunally hub isnt working correct for me. I have the following error: Error creating pull request: Unauthorized (HTTP 401). I tried see why this error and the best thing I had encountered is use `git config github.token`, but this didn't worked too. I working with a private repo.