# How to automate "pull-request creation" on GitHub?

Tags: java, python, git, github, version-control

I have forked a rep from my organization's repo.

I am updating some files on regular basis and pushing changes to my forked repo.

Lets say: My organization repo URL is : X and my forked repo URL: Y

I know we can use  "git pull-request" but I am not getting what exactly the command should be.

If anyone knows this then that would be of great help to me.

Comment: Did you read the docs for the `hub` CLI?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302570/automatically-open-a-pull-request-on-github-by-command-line

Answer (score 0):

`git request-pull [-p] <start> <url> [<end>]`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull